# Making tkinter buttons run function and append to list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, button, tkinter

In Python 3.x Tkinter, could you create a button that when clicked, executes a function and appends the button to a list, essentially creating a list of pressed buttons? Something like the below code.

```
list = []
btn = tkinter.Button("Text = 'button', command = funct and list.append(btn)
```

Answer (score 1):

yes, create a wrapper:

```
def callback():
    funct()
    list.append(btn)

btn = tkinter.Button(text = 'button', command = callback)
```

Then when you click on the button both events will be triggered.